# Hibernate object field

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two classes:

```
@Entity   
@Table(name = "movies")  
public class Movie implements Serializable {  
    @Id  
    private int movieID;  
    private String name;  
    private int year;  
    private Genre genre;  
    //constructor, getters, setters  
}  

@Entity  
@Table(name = "genres")  
public class Genreimplements Serializable {  
    @Id  
    private int genreID;  
    private String name;  
    //constructor, getters, setters  
}
```

Database tables are (simplified so you only see the fields):
     movies(int movieID, text name, int year, int genreID)
     genres(int genreID, text name)

How do I map the genreID field to the genre object in the Movie class (preferably using annotations)?

(I'm using jsf and hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this in Movie.class

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Genre.class)
@JoinColumn(name="GENRE_FK_COLUMN_NAME_IN_MOVIE_TABLE", referencedColumnName = "ID_OF_GENRE_TABLE")
private Genre genre;
```

Comment: Don't you mean `@ManyToOne`?